# Cocos2d v2.0: unable to add CCParticleSystem to scene

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

I'm trying to add CCParticleFlower to my Cocos2d v2.0 (with ARC enabled) HelloWorld scene.
That's the code I am running:

```
CCParticleFlower* system = [[CCParticleFlower alloc] initWithTotalParticles:10];
        // Set some parameters that can't be set in Particle Designer
//        system.positionType = kCCPositionTypeFree;
  //      system.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
         system.visible = TRUE;
         [system setDuration:4.0f];
         system.position = CGPointMake(150.0f, 100.0f);
         [self addChild:system z:0];
```

I tried several variants but I'm not quiet sure what I am doing wrong as I never managed to run it.

E.g.:

```
CCParticleSystem * system = [CCParticleFlower node];
system.position = CGPointMake(150.0f, 100.0f);
[self addChild:system];
```

Comment: hii......Try this may be it helps you... CCParticleSystem* system; system = [CCParticleFlower node]; [self addChild:system z:1 tag:1];

Comment: @femina thanks, but unfortunately doesn't work. I am wondering if it has something to do with the fact that I have v2.0 + ARC enabled..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure to include the texture that is used on the particle system in your project.
2. Try resetting the system and see if it works. [system reset]. You could even try [system scheduleUpdate] just in case its not updating correclty.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did work by adding the texture. I thought that was not needed for those effects as in the tutorial I had found was not super clear, but I know understand better.